# Unable to get navigation Version

Tags: android, kotlin

I wanted to add a dependency to gradle project file, each time I try to synchronize it I get this error:

```
`Could not get unknown property *navigationVersion* for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`
```

Here is the dependency below:

```
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
```

[image: Picture of the Error and dependency]

Comment: did you define `navigationVersion` ?

Comment: No. I never did

Answer (score 3):

According to [the developer docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation) the classpath should use androidx, so:

```
def nav_version = "2.3.0"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a variable that should have the version number for the plugin, replace it with this

```
def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha04"
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```

or directly as

```
classpath 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.0-alpha04'
```

Comment: Try a clean project and rebuild. It is not possible that you getting the same error as above after this fix.